# Filtering on multiple criteria in the same column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one sheet that has IDs for which I'd like to pull information about from another sheet.

Sheet 1 with IDs:

| Id |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

Sheet 2 with additional information:

| Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | $500 |
| A | $600 |
| A | $700 |
| B | $200 |
| B | $300 |
| B | $400 |
| C | $30 |
| C | $40 |
| C | $50 |

I would like returned all information from Sheet 2 that matches all the IDs in Sheet 1. The result I want:

| Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | $500 |
| A | $600 |
| A | $700 |
| B | $200 |
| B | $300 |
| B | $400 |

I have tried using =FILTER(Sheet2!A:B,Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A:A) but that only gets me the first ID:

| Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | $500 |
| A | $600 |
| A | $700 |

I've played around with changing Sheet1!A2 in the filter formula to Sheet1!A:A but that throws an error. How can I get information for all IDs? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `FILTER()` with `COUNTIFS()`.

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B,INDEX(COUNTIFS(A2:A,Sheet2!A2:A)))
```

#### *[FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)*

#### *[COUNTIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)*

Comment: Glad to know! If you found it working then please accept the answer (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with FILTER and REGEXMATCH:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A:B, REGEXMATCH (Sheet2!A:A,TEXTJOIN("|",1,Sheet1!A:A)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I'm not all that familiar with REGEXMATCH and TEXTJOIN so didn't think to use them.